# How to automate AWS ec2 instance config file updation

Tags: linux, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, automation

I have to update some specific file in an ec2 instance and restart the service manually. What is the best way to automate this process?

Answer (score 1):

[Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) is the best way to achieve what you are trying to do. It takes two lines of instructions ( to update a file and to restart a service). All you have to do is install Ansible on your control machine (the machine from which you want to control your EC2 instance). Only requirement is SSH access from your control machine to your EC2 instance.

You can control many instances from your control machine and do not have to install any agent on your EC2 instances. For what you are trying to do, it may take 30 minutes to install Ansible and run any of the standard playbooks. If you plan on doing similar tasks in the future, you should invest some time in Ansible (free).

Comment: The AWS SSM service also has the "RunAnsiblePlaybook" feature, which can be really handy. It does require the SSM agent to be installed on each server, and Ansible (although you can install Ansible through SSM once the SSM agent is installed).

Comment: @MarkB I agree. For something as simple as what OP is asking, installing an agent is an overkill. If there are lot more periodic work that has to be pushed, then I agree installing SSM agent is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You’ll want to use AWS System Manager in EC2 (SSM)

It uses an agent on the EC2 instance to allow configuration and updates, and is integrated into EC2. If you have a shell script it can run that on the instance from the console, cli or api.

[User Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/what-is-systems-manager.html)

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html